# Electrical lines breaking under low power

Tags: oxygen-not-included

In Oxygen Not Included I am experiencing breaks in electrical lines even though they are not carrying over 1000 W of power. The entire system has more than 1000 W, but the branches where the breaks are occurring do not.

Is this just a bug in the design of the game?

Comment: voted for close. this question is unclear and the asker did not come back to improve on it. He did not mark any of the answers as correct, so they did not seem to cover the question. But even more importantly oxygen not included is in early access (leaving it soon) and the version in which the behaviour was observed is already far outdated.

Comment: @BestGuess The question seems pretty clear to me and describes an unintuitive way that the power system works in ONI. The behavior exists in the current version, because it is intended, and David's answer is correct. I don't think failing to accept an answer is good reason to vote to close a question as unclear. Also, your answer to this question should be a comment and you don't have nearly enough rep to vote to close. What are you talking about?

Comment: @Matt: As i wrote in my answer (which is essentially exactly the same answer as written by david yell, just 2 hours earlier on my part), it is _unclear_ what tyler durden means with "Branches". There are no branches in oxygen not included, just circuits. he failed to update his question, respond to my answer and did not mark an answer as accepted (not even tylers). given all these aspects, the question is not suited to provide help to many players, because the answers are merely "interpretation" of what he might have meant instead of actual answers. And regarding my rep: I do.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the total wattage of equipment connected to your power source exceeds 1000W. This will cause the wires to degrade over time. Even if they are not using the power, when they do, the spike will be over 1000W and will cause damage.

The solution is to use transformers and heavy wires. Using this approach you can create a single high wattage line, and step the wattage down using a transformer, so that each sub-circuit has a maximum draw of 1000W. That is to say that the total wattage of equipment attached to the circuit is less than 1000W.

You might have multiple sub-circuits in order to meet the 1000W restriction, at least until you reach the upgraded wires technology.

If you'd like a more in-depth explanation this guide video is a good start.

Answer (score -2):

Please clarify what you mean with "branches". In oxygen not included each "power circuit" shares its power on every element. So if you have only one circuit, this might be your problem.
You can split your power network into different circuits with transformers.